# Windows Server 2008, IIS7 - hosting private-bower

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, bower, iisnode

Its been ten years since I worked with IIS. Windows Server 2008 is new to me. Now, I need to install a private-bower service on Windows Server 2008, and I'm not sure if I need IIS 7 and `iisnode` or if there is a better way.

Running private-bower, starts a server at `http://localhost:5678/`

1. What is the best way to expose that as a service for an internal network on Windows Server 2008?
2. Or in noob terms: how would I convert http:localhost:5678 to run in Win Server 2008 and IIS7?
3. I can install `node/npm.` So using node is an option, within IIS using `iisnode` and IIS7 (link below) but would I need to? Is there an easier way in IIS?

I'm not sure where to start to configure the `:5678 port` to be an external service, and how to keep it running, in a remote desktop login.

The links I've been using are:

private-bower: https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-bower

Node on IIS: 
    http://admin-ahead.com/blog/node-js-installation-windows-2008-r2-server/

iisnode:https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

But I need some help with Window Server 2008 and IIS 7, possibly a link describing ideal service configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found an example that is for Windows Server 2012:

The recommended way to install private-bower as a Windows Service:

https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower/wiki/Install%20as%20a%20Windows%20service